# Lib(s)uinput: creating joystick with more than one button

Tags: c, linux, uinput

I can't find information, how create joystick with several buttons on it using `uinput`/`suinput`. Example on `python` using `python-uinput`:

```
import uinput

def main():
    events = (
        uinput.BTN_JOYSTICK,
        uinput.ABS_X + (0, 255, 0, 0),
        uinput.ABS_Y + (0, 255, 0, 0),
        )

    with uinput.Device(events) as device:
        for i in range(20):
            # syn=False to emit an "atomic" (5, 5) event.
            device.emit(uinput.ABS_X, 5, syn=False)
            device.emit(uinput.ABS_Y, 5)
        device.emit_click(uinput.BTN_JOYSTICK)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you can see, in this example using `BTN_JOYSTICK` as button. And how create second button/addictional two `ABS_X`/`ABS_Y`?

Note: I'm using `python` as example, application language is `C` with `libsuinput`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More buttons — more button codes. Originally button codes are defined in the `linux/input.h` header from userspace perspective, or [`uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h?h=v4.7) from the kernel perspective. For python they are duplicated in the [`ev.py`](https://github.com/tuomasjjrasanen/python-uinput/blob/master/src/ev.py). As you can see, there are a lot of them and you're mostly interested in things between `BTN_JOYSTICK` and `BTN_THUMBR` (but `BTN_TRIGGER_HAPPY` values are also used by some). The most interesting ones are `BTN_THUMB`, `BTN_PINKIE`, `BTN_[ABC]`, `BTN_SELECT` and `BTN_START`.

As for additional axis, choose any between `ABS_X` and `ABS_MISC`. The most interesting additional ones are `ABS_R[XYZ]` and `ABS_HAT0[XYZ]`.

So to use that additional buttons/axis you just use these identifiers in the same fashion you use `BTN_JOYSTICK` with `ABS_X` and `ABS_Y`.

Now, another interesting question probably is what values from this list are used by real joysticks that you're trying to emulate. This values can be obtained by using [evtest](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/evtest/) or [evemu](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Evemu/) programs (using real joystick, of course). Some widely available joysticks (Xbox and PS3) were also [discussed here](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2013-April/008790.html) (as you can see, joysticks are very different in what button codes they produce). And to be really sure (or to emulate some device you can't check with evtest) you can also take a look at [real joystick drivers](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/input/joystick?h=v4.7) (just `BTN_` and `ABS_` things they use).

Comment: I see, you registred at ruSO. Please, public you answer here: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567511/libsuinput-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.